# StreetViewPanoramaView with ViewRenderer Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, google-street-view

I want to StreetViewPanoramaView of GoogleMaps on own project by Xamarin Forms. Then, I have tried on iOS with ViewRenderer. It works on iOS. However, when I tried Android with ViewRenderer. It does not work. Anything happens on the view. Please help me How can I do StreetViewPanoramaView on ViewRenderer.

I use this codes:

On Shared Project StreetView.xaml on Xamarin forms Project
public class StreetView: View
{
}
it works on iOS that I use

```
assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(StreetView), typeof(StreetViewRenderer))]
namespace Yournamespace.iOS.Renderer
{
    public class StreetViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<StreetView, PanoramaView>
    {
        PanoramaView panoramaView;

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<StreetView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control == null)
            {
                CGRect rect = new CGRect(0, 0, App.ScreenWidth, App.ScreenHeight);
                panoramaView = new PanoramaView(rect);
                SetNativeControl(panoramaView);

                if (SharedSystem.Current.CurrentVehicle.PlateNumber == null)
                {
                    SetCoordinate(40.968845, 29.065849);    
                }
                else
                    SetCoordinate(SharedSystem.Current.CurrentVehicle.DeviceLatitude.Value, SharedSystem.Current.CurrentVehicle.DeviceLongitude.Value);    



            }
            if (e.OldElement != null)
            {
                // Unsubscribe
                panoramaView.DidMoveToPanoramaNearCoordinate -= PanoramaView_DidMoveToPanoramaNearCoordinate;

                MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<Vehicle>(this, "SelectedPin");
            }
            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                // Subscribes
                MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Vehicle>(this, "SelectedPin", (sender) =>
                {
                    if(SharedSystem.Current.CurrentVehicle.PlateNumber == sender.PlateNumber)
                        SetCoordinate(sender.DeviceLatitude.Value,sender.DeviceLongitude.Value);
                });

                MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Vehicle>(this, "ScrollToVehicle", (sender) =>
                {
                    if (SharedSystem.Current.CurrentVehicle.PlateNumber == sender.PlateNumber)
                        SetCoordinate(sender.DeviceLatitude.Value, sender.DeviceLongitude.Value);
                });
                panoramaView.DidMoveToPanoramaNearCoordinate += PanoramaView_DidMoveToPanoramaNearCoordinate;
            }
        }

        public void SetCoordinate(double latitude, double longitude)
        {
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                CLLocationCoordinate2D location = new CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude, longitude);
                panoramaView.MoveNearCoordinate(location);

            });


        }

        void PanoramaView_DidMoveToPanoramaNearCoordinate(object sender, GMSPanoramaDidMoveToPanoramaNearCoordinateEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                Control.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
```

But any codes work on Android with ViewRenderer.
Please Help How can I do StreetViewPanoramaView on Android

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if someone made in Xamarin forms. From this what xamarin said "Android also supports loading street views from an Intent. To launch a street view, simply use the google.streetview URI scheme, as demonstrated in the following code:

var streetViewUri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse ( "google.streetview:cbll=42.374260,-71.120824&cbp=1,90,,0,1.0&mz=20");

var streetViewIntent = new Intent (Intent.ActionView, streetViewUri);

StartActivity (streetViewIntent);

[Link here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/maps_and_location/maps/maps-application/)